# How to obtain all values assoicated with a multi-column grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First off, I apologize if this question is not clear. I will extrapolate on what I mean here.

Basically, I am looking for a way to obtain all values in one column that correspond to a multi-column grouping. My original dataframe has three columns: latitude, longitude, and building ID. There are different building IDs that share the same latitude/longitude coordinates. I want to group together the latitude/longitude columns and indicate each building ID that is associated with those coordinates.

Right now, my dataframe looks like this:

```
     BldgID     |     Latitude     |      Longitude
--------------------------------------------------------- 
       1              30.48583            -70.57566
       2              27.87265            -67.28715
       3              30.48583            -70.57566
       4              45.26657            -75.14273
```

As can be seen, each building ID is paired with its latitude/longitude coordinates. Twi building IDs have the same coordinates. Because of that, I would like to group together the lat / lon columns and indicate all the building IDs that are associated with a set of coordinates.

I would like the output to look like this:

```
    Lat/Lon               |           BldgID
-------------------------------------------------------
('30.48583', '-70.57566')                1
('30.48583', '-70.57566')                3
('30.48583', '-70.57566')                9
('27.87265', '-67.28715')                2
('27.87265', '-67.28715')                6
('45.26657', '-75.14273')                4
('48.19456', '-81.23281')                12
```

You can see that building IDs 1, 3, and 9 are paired with their shared latitude / longitude coordinates. IDs 2 and 6 are also paired together. IDs 4 and 12 each have their own set of coordinates.

If I loop through the column grouping, it will print out which IDs correspond with the lat/lon coordinates, but I would like to capture this in a dataframe.

At first, I tried to do:

```
for j in df.groupby(['Latitude', 'Longitude']):
   data = pd.DataFrame(j)
```

But that wasn't working for me. I am sure there is an efficient way to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add a sample of the data and the expected output, it's not clear what you are trying to archive.

Comment: @MrNobody33 I edited my post to clarify what I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `set_index`, `agg` and `sort_values`:

```
df.set_index('BldgID').agg(tuple,1)\
  .reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Lat/Lon'}).sort_values('Lat/Lon')
```

Output:

```
   BldgID                Lat/Lon
1       2  (27.87265, -67.28715)
0       1  (30.48583, -70.57566)
2       3  (30.48583, -70.57566)
3       4  (45.26657, -75.14273)
```

Comment: This does what I needed! Thank you very much. I've now learned how to implement ```agg()``` and how useful it is.